# Unexpected redirect if upstream server redirect in nginx proxy_pass with URI specified

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

This is my reverse proxy server block

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name test.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_set_header HOST $host;
    }
}
```

I creates all endpoint in my upstream server without trailing slash, redirecting all trailing slash endpoint to it's non trailing slash endpoint in my upstream server as well, `test.com/foo/` will redirect to `test.com/foo`, everything is fine until I want proxy `test.com` to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/app/`, here's the server block

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name test.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/app/;
        proxy_set_header HOST $host;
    }
}
```

And this is what happened:

1. `test.com` redirect to `test.com/app`, expect `test.com`
2. `test.com/foo` still the same as expected
3. `test.com/foo/` redirect to `test.com/app/foo`, expect `test.com/foo`

Can't find the solution to this, any help?

Comment: Make your application aware that you have altered the URL path.

Comment: Can the solution is in the server block? not in the application

Comment: You will have to fix the application.

Comment: Use `curl -I http://test.com/foo/` to identify the exact value of the `Location` response header, and use `proxy_redirect` to change it.